# Finding partial string matches between list and elements of list of lists

Tags: python-3.x

I have a list of strings:

```
mylist = ['foo hydro', 'bar']
```

and a list of lists of strings called test:

```
testI = ['foo', 'bar']             ## should succeed
testJ = ['foo']                    ## should fail
testK = ['foo hydro']              ## should fail
testL = ['foo hydro', 'bar']       ## should succeed
testM = ['foo', 'bar', 'third']    ## should fail

test = [testI,testJ,testK,testL,testM]
```

I need to be able to check if there's a (partial or whole) string match between each element of each list in `test` and each element of `mylist`.

So, `testI` should succeed because `testI[0]` is a partial string match of `mylist[0]` *and* because `testI[1]` is a complete string match for  `mylist[1]`.

However, `testJ` and `testK` should each fail because they only match one of the two strings in `mylist`, and `testM` should fail because it contains an element which doesn't match with any element in `mylist`

So far, I've tried to play around with `any`:

```
for i in mylist:
    for j in test:
        for k in j:
            if any(i in b for b in k):
                print("An element of mylist matches an element of test")
```

So I can catch if any element of mylist matches any element in each list in test, but I can't work out a way to meet all the requirements.

Any suggestions? I'm happy to refactor the question if it makes dealing with it easier.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I want to suggest a solution to your problem.

Firstly, we create function that recognizes if a word is a substring of any word in another list:

```py
def is_substring_of_element_in_list(word, list_of_str):
    if len(list_of_str) == 0:
        return (False, -1)
    is_sub = any([word in s for s in list_of_str])
    if (is_sub == True):
        ix = [word in s for s in list_of_str].index(True)
    else: 
        ix = -1
    return is_sub, ix
```

Now, we can use this function to check if each word from the test list is a substring of a word on your list. Notice, we can use every word only once so we need to remove a string if a given word is a substring of.

```py
def is_list_is_in_mylist(t, mylist):
    mylist_now = sorted(mylist, key=len)
    test_now = sorted(t, key=len)
    counter = 0
    for word in t:
        is_sub, index = is_substring_of_element_in_list(word, mylist_now)
        if is_sub:
            mylist_now.pop(index)
            test_now.remove(word)
            counter += 1
    if counter == len(t) and counter == len(mylist):
        print("success")
    else:
        print("fail")
```

Pay attention, we need to sort the elements in the list to avoiding mistakes caused by the order of the words. For example, if `my_list = ['f', 'foo']` and `test1 = ['f', 'foo']` and `test2 = ['foo', 'f']` without sorting, one of the success and the other will be faild.

Now, you can iterate over your test with simple for loop:

```py
for t in test:
    is_list_is_in_mylist(t, mylist)
```

Comment: Thanks for your help, appreciate it. I added a bunch of tests including having a common word in both strings of mylist, like: ['foo hydro bar', 'bar'], and your test succeeded the new tests I wrote for that situation.

Answer (score 0):

i think this code probably match your conditions :

```
for t in test:
    counter = 0
    if len(t) == len(mylist):
        t = list(dict.fromkeys(t))
        temp = []
        for s in t:
            if not any([s in r for r in t if s != r]):
                temp.append(s)
        for l in temp:
            for m in mylist:
                if l in m:
                    counter = counter + 1
        if counter == len(mylist):
            print('successed')
        else:
            print('fail')
    else:
        print('fail')
```

Comment: This solution have a bug. For example ```testN = ['foo', 'foo']``` supposed to be failed but it return successful.

Comment: Not yet, check this: ```testO = ['foo hydro', 'foo'] ``` supposed to be failed but it return successful.

Comment: please tell me if you find any other bug.

Comment: I think you caused a critical bug. All the tests are failing now.